# CSS to make my wordpress nav bar thinner

Tags: css, nav

I hope you can help.
I am looking to make my main menu nav bar in Woo Canvas thinner, just wondered if there was a simple snippet of css that you could advise me to use to paste into Edit CSS at all?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post code and html for the main menu, create a demo on jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this CSS changes and see how it works:

```
.main-navigation ul.menu>li>a, .main-navigation ul.nav-menu>li>a {
    padding-top: 1.1em;
    padding-bottom: 1.1em;
}

.site-header .site-branding {
  margin-top: .7em;
}

.site-header .site-branding img, .site-header .site-logo-anchor img, .site-header .site-logo-link img {
    height: 2em;
    width: auto;
}
```

[image]